# Horizontal Collection View with different width cells

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewlayout

I have a `UICollectionView` where the width of the cells is dynamic based on text. When I set a spacing of `5px` between all cells, this is the distance between the 2 longest cells but all the other ones are a lot more spaced.

[image]

I need the spacing to be always the same, even when the cells are very small or very big.
Any idea on how to achieve this?

So far I'm setting the `minimumLineSpacingForSectionAt` and the size of the cell is calculated based on the width of the text.

Comment: The UICollectionViewFlowLayout cannot implementation this demand,You need to creat yourself UICollectionViewLayout.

Comment: Head over to google and search for `UICollectionView tag layout` ... lots and lots of examples and discussions, as well as 3rd-party implementations.